# R shiny, and tab Panels

Tags: r, input, shiny, tabs

I would like to know if it is possible to link several TabPanels in a R shiny app. I mean if we choose a certain option in Panel 1, I would like to have an update (with the choice of Panel 1) in Panel 2 for example.

Thank you so much

I am looking for a command or something like that.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you make your post reproducible by providing any code you've written so far?

Answer (score -1):

Create a tab panel
tabPanel(title, ..., value = title, icon = NULL)
Arguments
title   Display title for tab
... UI elements to include within the tab
value   The value that should be sent when tabsetPanel reports that this tab is selected. If omitted and tabsetPanel has an id, then the title will be used..
icon    Optional icon to appear on the tab. This attribute is only valid when using a tabPanel within a navbarPage.

Comment: I don't really understand. I want that if in the first panel the user selects "valueA" for input$Name1 then have an update of input$Name2 which take the value "valueA" in the Panel 2.